# Suppose $A_{1},\; A_{2},\ldots,\; A_{n}$ are independent events. Show that $A_{1}^{c},\ldots,A_{n}^{c}$ are independent.

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $A_{1},\; A_{2},\ldots,\; A_{n}$ are independent events. Show that $A_{1}^{c},\ldots,A_{n}^{c}$ are independent.

Solution:

We begin with $n=2$. 
$$\begin{align}
P(A_{1}^{c}\bigcap A_{2}^{c}) 
  &= P\left(\left(A_{1}\bigcup A_{2}\right)^{c}\right) \cr
  &=1-P\left(A_{1}\bigcup A_{2}\right) \cr
  &=1-\left(P(A_{1})+P(A_{2})-P(A_{1}\bigcap A_{2})\right) \cr
  &=1-P(A_{1})-P(A_{2})+P(A_{1})P(A_{2}) \cr
  &=\left(1-P(A_{1})\right)\left(1-P(A_{2})\right) \cr
  &=P(A_{1}^{c})P(A_{2}^{c}).
\end{align}$$

So, $A_{1}^{c},\, A_{2}^{c}$ are independent. Then by induction,
$A_{1}^{c},\ldots,A_{n}^{c}$ are independent.

Is my proof rigorous/complete?

Comment: Well, it looks fine, but I'm afraid you'll have to flesh out the "Then by induction $\,A_1^c,...,A_n^c\,$ are independent"

Comment: You have shown it holds for one operator $\cap$. Now you can assume it holds for arbitrary $n$ operators and then prove that it holds for $n+1$. This will be proof by induction

Comment: Have you managed to solve the problem?

Comment: I don't think that is enough. You have to show for an arbitary combination as well.